# Creating new post via Rails Console and passing validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rails-console, pry

Ruby newbie here. I'm currently working on an assignment that has me validate posts. This is what my **post.rb** looks like:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :topic

  default_scope { order('created_at DESC') }

   validates :title, length: { minimum: 5 }, presence: true
   validates :body, length: { minimum: 20 }, presence: true
   validates :topic, presence: true
   validates :user, presence: true
end
```

Using the console (I'm using Pry), I ought to create a new post that passes the validation. I have no issues passing the title and body, but I'm trying to understand the logic on how to pass it for topic and user. I would think that it wants a user_id or topic_id but I'm not clear on how to implement that.

If I enter (purposely leaving out user and topic):

```
 [1] pry(main)> p = Post.new(title: 'Longer than 5', body: 'This is the body. There should be more than 20 characters here in order to pass validation')
 => #<Post:0x007fee71a12180
 id: nil,
 title: "Longer than 5",
 body:
  "This is the body. There should be more than 20 characters here in order to pass validation",
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil,
 user_id: nil,
 topic_id: nil>
[2] pry(main)> p.valid?
=> false
[3] pry(main)> p.errors.full_messages
=> ["Topic can't be blank", "User can't be blank"]
```

I understand that error (user and topic can't be blank). I tried adding:

```
topic: 'This is my Topic', user: 'myuserid'
```

But I'm getting a syntax error.

How is the console expecting me to check if the user and topic are present?

Comment: Check out the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) and you could refactor the Post model to [this](https://gist.github.com/daslicious/e822440f41470498ce73)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either pass an instance of the `Topic` and `User` classes like this:

```
topic = Topic.create
user = User.create
p = Post.create(title: 'Longer than 5', body: 'This is the body. There should be more than 20 characters here in order to pass validation', topic: topic, user: user)
```

Or you can use the ids:

```
topic = Topic.create
user = User.create
p = Post.create(title: 'Longer than 5', body: 'This is the body. There should be more than 20 characters here in order to pass validation', topic_id: topic.id, user_id: user.id)
```

Either way the database will store the ids.